# Write LaTeX3 variable to aux file and recover it

Tags: expl3

I was wondering how to write a LaTeX3 variable to an aux file and read it in at the very beginning of a document. The motivation of this problem is that I would like to get rid of my LaTeX2 counters and implement them via LaTeX3 variables. A LaTeX2 counter I can write out as follows

```
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{foo}{\number\value{bar}}}
}
```

But something similar

```
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\int_set:Nn\l__foo{\l__bar}}
}
```

does not work.

Is there something similar defined for LaTeX3? Or is this already to early to ask for?

Comment: The problem is in the category codes; only @ is made into a letter when the aux file is being read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume you have two integer variables `\g_maxmaier_foo_int` and `\l_maxmaier_bar_int` and that, at end document, you want to save the setting

```
\int_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_int { \int_eval:n { \l_maxmaier_bar_int } }
```

in the aux file, so that the value of the `foo` variable is set at the beginning of the next run.

You have to surround this in `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`, otherwise the commands would not be interpreted correctly. Note also that the setting to the `foo` variable must be global, because the aux file is read inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g_maxmaier_foo_int
\int_new:N \l_maxmaier_bar_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\setbar}{m}
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l_maxmaier_bar_int { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showfoo}{}
 {
  \int_to_arabic:n { \g_maxmaier_foo_int }
 }

\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \int_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_int { \int_eval:n { \l_maxmaier_bar_int } }
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The value of \texttt{foo} is \showfoo

\setbar{42}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Contents of the aux file

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_int {42}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

Some comments.

1. Adding `\int_eval:n` (or its synonym `\int_use:n`) is essential, otherwise LaTeX would write

   ```
   \int_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_int { \l_maxmaier_bar_int }
   ```

   which would be completely useless, because it would assign the value of `\l_maxmaier_bar_int` current at execution time, that is, when the `.aux` file is being read; we want instead to fix the value of the variable *at writing time* (in the previous LaTeX run).
2. For the same reason above, it's important to use `\iow_now:cx` (a variant for `\iow_now:Nx`) so its argument is fully expanded at writing time.
3. The token `^^J` makes a new line when a list of tokens is written in the `.aux` file. It's the analog of `\n` in other programming languages.

Comment: I've been playing around with your solution and have a couple of questions. 1) Why do you make use of `int_eval:n` while setting the variable in the aux file instead of `int_use:N`? Wouldn't it be enough to write `\int_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_int { \l_maxmaier_bar_int } }`? According to source3.pdf if an integer is expected one can omit `\int_use:N`. Therefore my conclusion was to omit the eval, too. 2) What are the tokens '^^J` for? Thank you very much for your solution so far!

Comment: @MaxMaier I added a final comment; let me know if you have other doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend replacing LaTeX2e counters with `\int...` variables (although they are `\count` registers anyway) since this needs `\ExplSyntaxOn` ... in the `.aux` file already.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_foo_int

\int_new:N \l_bar_int
\int_set:Nn \l_bar_int {100}


\begin{document}
The~value~of~foo~is~\int_use:N \l_foo_int
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\int_set:Nn \l_foo_int\expandafter{\int_use:N \l_bar_int}}
\makeatother




\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't thought about putting ExplSyntaxOn/Off into the aux file. Does this have any side effects if I put it only around my commands and nothing else?

Comment: @MaxMaier: If you don't write `ExplSyntaxOn/Off` into the `.aux` file LaTeX2 will not understand your code, that's the backdraw!