# Compiling questions in exam class

Tags: exam

While using the exam class, is there a way of compiling all the questions and putting them together at the beginning of the document? I would want the end result to look something like the result of the following code. First all the questions and then each question with a solution box.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
 \question First Question
 \question Second Question
\end{questions}

\newpage

 \begin{questions}
  \question First question
  \begin{EnvFullwidth}
   \begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    This looks good,
   \end{solutionbox}

  \end{EnvFullwidth}

  \question Second question
  \begin{EnvFullwidth}
   \begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    Not so good.
   \end{solutionbox}
  \end{EnvFullwidth}

 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to automate this, so I only have the questions typed in one place and on compilation, it will extract them and create the first part? Ideally, something that looks like:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\begin{document}
\printallquestions

\newpage

 \begin{questions}
  \question First question
  \begin{EnvFullwidth}
   \begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    This looks good,
   \end{solutionbox}

  \end{EnvFullwidth}

  \question Second question
  \begin{EnvFullwidth}
   \begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    Not so good.
   \end{solutionbox}
  \end{EnvFullwidth}

 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably, [Answers at the end of the exam document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237372/106162) asks the reverse (print all answers at end) and has a number of answers.

Comment: The difference is I want the questions to appear twice. Once at the beginning with no space for answers, and then again with space for each answer.

Comment: I appreciate they're different questions, though I think the biggest complication is here you want the questions to be printed before they've been defined.  How do you want `\printallquestions` to appear - with space for answers or not?

Comment: No space for answers. Basically the exam should contain all the questions and then a copy of each part with the corresponding space for filling in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work, although I expect there may be a more robust solution.

Include all your questions in a command, then execute that command twice after `\begin{document}` (once with `\noprintanswers` and again after `\printanswers`).

I also added a custom environment that encloses every solution in an `EnvFullwidth` environment so you don't have to do that manually every time.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newenvironment{mysolution}
{\begin{EnvFullwidth}
\begin{solution}
}
{
\end{solution}
\end{EnvFullwidth}
}

\newcommand{\myquestions}{%
    \begin{questions}
    \question First question

    \begin{mysolution}
    This looks good,
    \end{mysolution}

    \question Second question
    \begin{mysolution}
    Not so good.
    \end{mysolution}

    \end{questions}
}

\begin{document}
\noprintanswers
\myquestions

\newpage
\printanswers
\myquestions
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A little bit of modification on this made it work. I actually needed to not remove the answers but also the answer boxes (but be able to have both if if want the answers). I used your idea but in a block around the first myquestions I redefined the solution environment to gobble its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Using erik's answer, I constructed this MWE of what I want, where the answers can be shown or hidden in the second part. However, I'd still like a cleaner solution like writing the question parts into a separate file.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{mySol}[1][1in]{
\begin{EnvFullwidth}
 \begin{solutionbox}{#1}
  \BODY
 \end{solutionbox}
\end{EnvFullwidth}}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\myquestions{
 \begin{questions}
  \question First question
\begin{mySol}
    This looks good,
\end{mySol}
  \clearpage
  \question Second question
  \begin{mySol}
    Not so good.
  \end{mySol}

 \end{questions}}

 {\RenewEnviron{mySol}[1][\relax]{\relax}
  \renewcommand\newpage{\relax}
  \renewcommand\clearpage{\relax}
  \myquestions
}
\clearpage
\myquestions

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there's definitely a case for setting some variable `\anslength` and using that in the argument of `solutionbox` and swapping that from `2in` to `0in` and then compiling with answers off to produce a copy with just the questions and no space for answers and then stitching together the PDFs with [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).  Similarly I think answers to [Answers at the end of the exam document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/237372/106162) could be adaptedly easily enough to print a question list at the end of the question and the necessary reordering not a huge task by hand.

For the MWE given by the OP, the following does the job.  Questions are written to the `aux` file (based on egreg's solution to [Write LaTeX3 variable to aux file and recover it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298500/106162)) and then retrieved, this will therefore need to be compiled twice.  `\PrintQuestions` prints the questions in the `questions` environment, which does lead to duplication of labels, probably an `enumerate` environment is sufficient.  I have no idea why `\item[]` is necessary but LaTeX was very unhappy if I didn't include a plain `\item` (`\question` also did the job) and as `[]` hides the label it doesn't cause much disturbance.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_exam_beginprint_seq
\seq_new:N \g_exam_beginprint_seq

\NewDocumentCommand \WriteQuestion { +m } {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \l_exam_beginprint_seq { #1 }
    \question #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintQuestions { } {
    \begin{questions}
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_exam_beginprint_seq { \question ~ ##1 }
        \item[] 
    \end{questions}
}

\cs_new:Npn \QuestionFromAux #1 {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_exam_beginprint_seq { #1 }
}

\AtEndDocument {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_exam_beginprint_seq {
        \iow_now:cx { @auxout } {
            \token_to_str:N \QuestionFromAux { #1 }
            ^^J
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\PrintQuestions

\newpage

\begin{questions}
\WriteQuestion{First question}
\begin{EnvFullwidth}
\begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    This looks good,
\end{solutionbox}
\end{EnvFullwidth}

\WriteQuestion{Second question}
\begin{EnvFullwidth}
\begin{solutionbox}{2in}
    Not so good.
\end{solutionbox}
\end{EnvFullwidth}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]