# Write a floating point LaTeX3 variable to an aux file and recover it

Tags: expl3

A while ago I asked the question how to write an **integer** variable into an aux file and read it: [Write LaTeX3 variable to aux file and recover it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298500/write-latex3-variable-to-aux-file-and-recover-it)

Now, I'm faced with an almost identical problem where I have to write/read a variable to/from the aux file but this time it is of type **floating point**. Have a look at the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_maxmaier_foo_fp
\fp_new:N \l_maxmaier_bar_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\setbar}{m}
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l_maxmaier_bar_fp { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showfoo}{}
 {
  \fp_to_tl:N \g_maxmaier_foo_fp
 }

\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \fp_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_fp { \fp_to_scientific:N \l_maxmaier_bar_fp }
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The value of \texttt{foo} is \showfoo

\setbar{42}

\end{document}
```

While executing LaTeX I get an error. If we look into the the aux file we find:

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn \s__fp \__fp_chk:w 00\s__fp_exact ;{4.2e1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The floating point number is correct but the variable name is screwed up. I would have expected an aux file of the following form:

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_fp {4.2e1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Why can't I use the variable name in this place as before when I used integers? Is there any suggested work around available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For implementation reasons, the macro representing a floating point variable is not `\protected` against `x` expansion. Just tell LaTeX not to expand it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \g_maxmaier_foo_fp
\fp_new:N \l_maxmaier_bar_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\setbar}{m}
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l_maxmaier_bar_fp { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showfoo}{}
 {
  \fp_to_tl:N \g_maxmaier_foo_fp
 }

\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \fp_gset:Nn \exp_not:N \g_maxmaier_foo_fp { \fp_to_scientific:N \l_maxmaier_bar_fp }
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The value of \texttt{foo} is \showfoo

\setbar{42}

\end{document}
```

The contents of the `aux` file will be

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_gset:Nn \g_maxmaier_foo_fp {4.2e1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: That works perfectly! LaTeX macro expansion is still a miracle for me ;) Thanks for the explanation.