# expl3 sequence name replaced by \s__seq when written to the .aux file

Tags: expl3

I'm trying to adapt [this egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298512/18401) but I'm facing a very strange phenomenon.

As shown by the following MCE, the similar lines that are supposed to be written to the `.aux` file:

```
\int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {#1}
\seq_put_right:Nn \g_integers_seq {#1}
```

result on the expected one for the 1st one but, in the 2nd one, `\g_integers_seq` is changed in `\s__seq`!

Here is the `.aux` file's content:

```
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {1}
\seq_put_right:Nn \s__seq {1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {2}
\seq_put_right:Nn \s__seq {2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_integers_seq
\int_new:N \g_integer_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewInteger}{m}
{
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {#1}
    ^^J
    \seq_put_right:Nn \g_integers_seq {#1}
    ^^J
    \token_to_str:N \ExplSyntaxOff
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\NewInteger{1}
\NewInteger{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because `\g_integers_seq` is not a protected command.

Answer (score 2):

`\g_integers_seq` is not a protected command and doesn't survive `x` expansion.

You simply do `\iow_now:cn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_integers_seq
\int_new:N \g_integer_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewInteger}{m}
{
  \iow_now:cn { @auxout }
   {
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    ^^J
    \int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {#1}
    ^^J
    \seq_put_right:Nn \g_integers_seq {#1}
    ^^J
    \ExplSyntaxOff
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\NewInteger{1}
\NewInteger{2}
\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file will be

```latex
\relax 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {1}
\seq_put_right:Nn \g_integers_seq {1}
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\int_gset:Nn \g_integer_int {2}
\seq_put_right:Nn \g_integers_seq {2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In the code you quote, `\iow_now:cx` is necessary for doing the computation through `\int_eval:n`.

If you need to do computations, you need to protect `\g_integers_seq` from expansion with `\exp_not:N` or `\token_to_str:N`.

Comment: OK but why `\g_integer_int` does survive `x` expansion? And where `\s__seq` does come from?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Because it's an unexpandable token defined with `\countdef`.

Comment: Do you mean any `\g_..._int`is an unexpandable token defined with `\countdef`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Yes. Currently the LaTeX2e `\newcount` macro is used, for compatibility with the allocation mechanism.

Comment: And where the name `s__seq` does come from?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It's the internal implementation of sequence variables.